# How do I set $? in functions called by PS1?

Tags: command-prompt, bash, ps1

I currently have a prompt in bash that calls a function to output the return code of the last command run (if non-zero):

```bsh
exit_code_prompt()
{
    local exit_code=$?
    if [ $exit_code -ne 0 ]
    then
        tput setaf 1
        printf "%s" $exit_code
        tput sgr0
    fi
}


PS1='$(exit_code_prompt)\$ '
```

This works rather nicely, except for `$?` not resetting unless another command is run:

```
$ echo "works"
works
$ command_not_found
bash: command_not_found: command not found
127$ 
127$ 
127$ 
127$ echo "works"
works
$
```

Is it possible to reset/unset the value of `$?` for the parent shell the first time `exit_code_prompt()` is run such that it does not continue to repeat the value in the prompt?

Many thanks, Steve.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?
This may give you additional trouble, if you want to test some script snippet manually over the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that if you don't issue another command, `$?` isn't changing. So when your prompt gets reevaluated, it is correctly emitting `127`. There isn't really a workaround for this except manually typing another command at the prompt.

edit: Actually I lied, there are always ways to store state, so you can store the value of `$?` and check if it's *changed*, and clear the prompt if it has. But since you're in a subshell, your options are pretty limited: You'd have to use a file or something equally dirty to store the value.

Comment: I don't need to store state, merely reset it after the printf if it's not equal to 0 --- I know when I wish to do it, just not how (and/or if it's possible)

Comment: @StephenWattam but if you don't store state, how can you tell the difference between a prompt immediately following a command and a prompt *not* following a command?

Comment: I was coming at this from a different angle, using `$?` as the state and setting it to zero after one output.

Comment: @StephenWattam right, but I don't think there's a way to do that within the `PS1` or `PROMPT_COMMAND`. Thus, you need an external way to check if it has changed. You can't simply force it back to `0`.

Comment: I feared as much.  The only solution I could come up with was `PROMPT_COMMAND="bash"`, but that's hilariously poor :-).

Comment: Without being able to alter how bash runs its prompts, it seems the scoping rules do indeed prevent me from touching anything --- Many thanks for the help.  This has to be the only time ever someone has wanted features from PHP in another language :-).